How to write custom message into Sentry with tag?
On Laravel 11 site I want to write  message into sentry with tag "InvalidDataEvent" in event handler.
Googling I found page Laravel and Sentry: How to set a custom tag in Sentry?
and make in event handler :
public function handle(InvalidDataEvent $event): void
{
    $errorMessage = 'Invalid Data Event: ' . $event->message;
    if (app()->bound('sentry')) {
        app('sentry')->withScope(function (\Sentry\State\Scope $scope) use ($errorMessage): void {
            $scope->setLevel(\Sentry\Severity::warning());

            // ERROR POINTING AT ROW BELOW
            $scope->setTag('InvalidDataEvent', app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class)->headers->get('InvalidDataEvent'));

            app('sentry')->captureException($errorMessage);
        });
    }
    /* Sentry\State\Scope::setTag(): Argument #2 ($value) must be of type string, null given, called in /Project/app/Listeners/InvalidDataListener.php on line 26 */

    if(App::isLocal()) {
        throw new \ErrorException($errorMessage);
    }

}

But error raised :
Sentry\State\Scope::setTag(): Argument #2 ($value) must be of type string, null given, called in /Project/app/Listeners/InvalidDataListener.php on line 26

a) Not sure what is $value var and how to fix it ?
b) how to convert string $errorMessage into Throwable class in line :
app('sentry')->captureException($errorMessage);

?
REMADE BLOCK:
I remade in event handler :
if (app()->bound('sentry')) {
    app('sentry')->withScope(function (\Sentry\State\Scope $scope) use ($errorMessage): void {


        $customEvent = app(Request::class)->headers->get('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', 'DTag');
        \Log::info($customEvent); // In log file I see value "DTag" - so this code is run
        $scope->setTag('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', $customEvent);


        app('sentry')->captureException(new \Exception($errorMessage));
    });
}

But in sentry.io/projects/myproject/ console I did not find any new events, only old events from yesterday which were defined in bootstrap/app.php:
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )

    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->alias([
            'checkAuthPermissions' => CheckAuthPermissionsMiddleware::class
        ]);
                })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        Integration::handles($exceptions);
    })->create();

after I have installed the package...
PS. Please point to related manuals - I searched without success...
"laravel/framework": "^11.9",
"sentry/sentry-laravel": "^4.7",

CHECKS BLOCK:
Sure in .env file I have :
SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN=https://XXXX.ingest.us.sentry.io/XXX
SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE=1.0
VITE_SENTRY_DSN_PUBLIC="${SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN}"

In config/sentry.php (I did not modify it yet):
<?php

/**
 * Sentry Laravel SDK configuration file.
 *
 * @see https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/configuration/options/
 */
return [

    // @see https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/dsn-explainer/
    'dsn' => env('SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN', env('SENTRY_DSN')),

    // @see https://spotlightjs.com/
    // 'spotlight' => env('SENTRY_SPOTLIGHT', false),

    // @see: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/configuration/options/#logger
    // 'logger' => Sentry\Logger\DebugFileLogger::class, // By default this will log to `storage_path('logs/sentry.log')`

    // The release version of your application
    // Example with dynamic git hash: trim(exec('git --git-dir ' . base_path('.git') . ' log --pretty="%h" -n1 HEAD'))
    'release' => env('SENTRY_RELEASE'),

    // When left empty or `null` the Laravel environment will be used (usually discovered from `APP_ENV` in your `.env`)
    'environment' => env('SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT'),

    // @see: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/configuration/options/#sample-rate
    'sample_rate' => env('SENTRY_SAMPLE_RATE') === null ? 1.0 : (float)env('SENTRY_SAMPLE_RATE'),

    // @see: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/configuration/options/#traces-sample-rate
    'traces_sample_rate' => env('SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE') === null ? null : (float)env('SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE'),

    // @see: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/configuration/options/#profiles-sample-rate
    'profiles_sample_rate' => env('SENTRY_PROFILES_SAMPLE_RATE') === null ? null : (float)env('SENTRY_PROFILES_SAMPLE_RATE'),

    // @see: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/configuration/options/#send-default-pii
    'send_default_pii' => env('SENTRY_SEND_DEFAULT_PII', false),

    // @see: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/configuration/options/#ignore-exceptions
    // 'ignore_exceptions' => [],

    // @see: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/configuration/options/#ignore-transactions
    'ignore_transactions' => [
        // Ignore Laravel's default health URL
        '/up',
    ],

    // Breadcrumb specific configuration
    'breadcrumbs' => [
        // Capture Laravel logs as breadcrumbs
        'logs' => env('SENTRY_BREADCRUMBS_LOGS_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture Laravel cache events (hits, writes etc.) as breadcrumbs
        'cache' => env('SENTRY_BREADCRUMBS_CACHE_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture Livewire components like routes as breadcrumbs
        'livewire' => env('SENTRY_BREADCRUMBS_LIVEWIRE_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture SQL queries as breadcrumbs
        'sql_queries' => env('SENTRY_BREADCRUMBS_SQL_QUERIES_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture SQL query bindings (parameters) in SQL query breadcrumbs
        'sql_bindings' => env('SENTRY_BREADCRUMBS_SQL_BINDINGS_ENABLED', false),

        // Capture queue job information as breadcrumbs
        'queue_info' => env('SENTRY_BREADCRUMBS_QUEUE_INFO_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture command information as breadcrumbs
        'command_info' => env('SENTRY_BREADCRUMBS_COMMAND_JOBS_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture HTTP client request information as breadcrumbs
        'http_client_requests' => env('SENTRY_BREADCRUMBS_HTTP_CLIENT_REQUESTS_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture send notifications as breadcrumbs
        'notifications' => env('SENTRY_BREADCRUMBS_NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED', true),
    ],

    // Performance monitoring specific configuration
    'tracing' => [
        // Trace queue jobs as their own transactions (this enables tracing for queue jobs)
        'queue_job_transactions' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_QUEUE_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture queue jobs as spans when executed on the sync driver
        'queue_jobs' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_QUEUE_JOBS_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture SQL queries as spans
        'sql_queries' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_SQL_QUERIES_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture SQL query bindings (parameters) in SQL query spans
        'sql_bindings' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_SQL_BINDINGS_ENABLED', false),

        // Capture where the SQL query originated from on the SQL query spans
        'sql_origin' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_SQL_ORIGIN_ENABLED', true),

        // Define a threshold in milliseconds for SQL queries to resolve their origin
        'sql_origin_threshold_ms' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_SQL_ORIGIN_THRESHOLD_MS', 100),

        // Capture views rendered as spans
        'views' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_VIEWS_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture Livewire components as spans
        'livewire' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_LIVEWIRE_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture HTTP client requests as spans
        'http_client_requests' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_HTTP_CLIENT_REQUESTS_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture Laravel cache events (hits, writes etc.) as spans
        'cache' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_CACHE_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture Redis operations as spans (this enables Redis events in Laravel)
        'redis_commands' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_REDIS_COMMANDS', false),

        // Capture where the Redis command originated from on the Redis command spans
        'redis_origin' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_REDIS_ORIGIN_ENABLED', true),

        // Capture send notifications as spans
        'notifications' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED', true),

        // Enable tracing for requests without a matching route (404's)
        'missing_routes' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_MISSING_ROUTES_ENABLED', false),

        // Configures if the performance trace should continue after the response has been sent to the user until the application terminates
        // This is required to capture any spans that are created after the response has been sent like queue jobs dispatched using `dispatch(...)->afterResponse()` for example
        'continue_after_response' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_CONTINUE_AFTER_RESPONSE', true),

        // Enable the tracing integrations supplied by Sentry (recommended)
        'default_integrations' => env('SENTRY_TRACE_DEFAULT_INTEGRATIONS_ENABLED', true),
    ],

];

In config/app.php - no "sentry" lines:
Sure I have cleared config.
bootstrap/app.php:
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->alias([
        'checkAuthPermissions' => CheckAuthPermissionsMiddleware::class
    ]);
            })

->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    Integration::handles($exceptions);
})->create();


Which options Did I miss ?  Especailly in config/app.php ?

REMADE BLOCK # 2:
After I added Sentry alias into config/app.php file and ServiceProvider into bootstrap/providers.php file
example :
Route::get('/check-sentry', function () {
    if (app()->bound('sentry')) {
        app('sentry')->captureException(new \Exception('There is a exception on Sentry check'));
    }
    return 'Sentry is working well';
});

works ok.
But when I try to add custom tag to this code :
Route::get('/check-sentry', function () {
    if (app()->bound('sentry')) {

        app('sentry')->withScope(function (\Sentry\State\Scope $scope) use ($errorMessage): void {
                $scope->setLevel(\Sentry\Severity::warning());

            $customEvent = app(Request::class)->headers->get('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', 'DTag');
            $scope->setTag('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', $customEvent);

            app('sentry')->captureException(new \Exception('There is a exception on Sentry check'));
        });

    }
    return 'Sentry is working well';
});

I got error :
[2024-08-13 09:23:13] local.ERROR: Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$headers {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined property: Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Request::$headers at laravel-serializable-closure://function () {
    if (\\app()->bound('sentry')) {

        \\app('sentry')->withScope(function (\\Sentry\\State\\Scope $scope): void {
                $scope->setLevel(\\Sentry\\Severity::warning());
            $customEvent = \\app(\\Request::class)->headers->get('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', 'DTag');
            $scope->setTag('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', $customEvent);

            \\app('sentry')->captureException(new \\Exception('There is a exception on Sentry check'));
        });

    }
    return 'Sentry is working well';
}:7)
[stacktrace]
#0 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(256): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 laravel-serializable-closure://function () {
    if (\\app()->bound('sentry')) {

        \\app('sentry')->withScope(function (\\Sentry\\State\\Scope $scope): void {
                $scope->setLevel(\\Sentry\\Severity::warning());
            $customEvent = \\app(\\Request::class)->headers->get('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', 'DTag');
            $scope->setTag('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', $customEvent);

            \\app('sentry')->captureException(new \\Exception('There is a exception on Sentry check'));
        });

    }
    return 'Sentry is working well';
}(7): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\{closure}()
#2 /projectPath/vendor/sentry/sentry/src/State/Hub.php(97): Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteFileRegistrar::{closure}()
#3 laravel-serializable-closure://function () {
    if (\\app()->bound('sentry')) {

        \\app('sentry')->withScope(function (\\Sentry\\State\\Scope $scope): void {
                $scope->setLevel(\\Sentry\\Severity::warning());
            $customEvent = \\app(\\Request::class)->headers->get('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', 'DTag');
            $scope->setTag('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', $customEvent);

            \\app('sentry')->captureException(new \\Exception('There is a exception on Sentry check'));
        });

    }
    return 'Sentry is working well';
}(5): Sentry\\State\\Hub->withScope()
#4 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/CallableDispatcher.php(40): Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteFileRegistrar::{closure}()
#5 /projectPath/vendor/sentry/sentry-laravel/src/Sentry/Laravel/Tracing/Routing/TracingCallableDispatcherTracing.php(21): Illuminate\\Routing\\CallableDispatcher->dispatch()
#6 /projectPath/vendor/sentry/sentry-laravel/src/Sentry/Laravel/Tracing/Routing/TracingRoutingDispatcher.php(34): Sentry\\Laravel\\Tracing\\Routing\\TracingCallableDispatcherTracing->Sentry\\Laravel\\Tracing\\Routing\\{closure}()
#7 /projectPath/vendor/sentry/sentry-laravel/src/Sentry/Laravel/Tracing/Routing/TracingCallableDispatcherTracing.php(20): Sentry\\Laravel\\Tracing\\Routing\\TracingRoutingDispatcher->wrapRouteDispatch()
#8 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(238): Sentry\\Laravel\\Tracing\\Routing\\TracingCallableDispatcherTracing->dispatch()
#9 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(209): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runCallable()
#10 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(808): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#11 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(144): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#12 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#13 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#14 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(88): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#15 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#16 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#17 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#18 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#19 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#20 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#21 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#22 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#23 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(75): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#24 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#25 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#26 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(807): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#27 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(786): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#28 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(750): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#29 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(739): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#30 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(201): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#31 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(144): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#32 /projectPath/vendor/sentry/sentry-laravel/src/Sentry/Laravel/Http/FlushEventsMiddleware.php(13): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#33 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Sentry\\Laravel\\Http\\FlushEventsMiddleware->handle()
#34 /projectPath/vendor/sentry/sentry-laravel/src/Sentry/Laravel/Http/SetRequestIpMiddleware.php(45): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#35 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Sentry\\Laravel\\Http\\SetRequestIpMiddleware->handle()
#36 /projectPath/vendor/sentry/sentry-laravel/src/Sentry/Laravel/Http/SetRequestMiddleware.php(31): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#37 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Sentry\\Laravel\\Http\\SetRequestMiddleware->handle()
#38 /projectPath/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Features/SupportDisablingBackButtonCache/DisableBackButtonCacheMiddleware.php(19): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#39 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Livewire\\Features\\SupportDisablingBackButtonCache\\DisableBackButtonCacheMiddleware->handle()
#40 /projectPath/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(59): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#41 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle()
#42 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#43 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#44 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#45 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#46 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#47 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#48 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#49 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#50 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(110): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#51 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#52 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#53 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle()
#54 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#55 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle()
#56 /projectPath/vendor/sentry/sentry-laravel/src/Sentry/Laravel/Tracing/Middleware.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#57 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Sentry\\Laravel\\Tracing\\Middleware->handle()
#58 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#59 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#60 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(145): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#61 /projectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(1188): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#62 /projectPath/public/index.php(17): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->handleRequest()
#63 {main}
"}

PS. I try to add error message and tag in one request... Is it correct?

This question is similar to: Laravel and Sentry: How to set a custom tag in Sentry?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your setTag doesnt work may be due to sometimes InvalidDataEvent value doesnt available in the request. so in order to resolve you can pass the default value to your InvalidDataEvent
$customEvent = app(Request::class)->headers->get('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', 'DTag');

$scope->setTag('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', $customEvent);

If the Invalid Data Event is missing then it will use DTag
and then generate a thrwable exception from a error message
$throwableException = new \Exception($errorMessage);

app('sentry')->captureException($throwableException);

config/app.php
'providers' => [
    Sentry\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [
    'Sentry' => Sentry\Laravel\Facade::class,
],

Check sentry using route
Route::get('/check-sentry', function () {
    if (app()->bound('sentry')) {
        app('sentry')->captureException(new \Exception('There is a exception on Sentry check'));
    }
    return 'Sentry is working well';
});


Please read REMADE BLOCK

@PetroGromovo Did you checked the Sentry Configuration in ENV and config/sentry.php and also config/app.php should have a provider added of sentry Also did you cleared the config and cache using php artisan command ?

Please read  CHECKS BLOCK

In order to Bootstrap the provider you will need to add Sentry Provider and alias in the config/app.php. also add Provider and alias in config/app.php , also make a test route to check sentry

Please read REMADE BLOCK # 2

This may occur if the Request is not defined on the top of Route or controller use Illuminate\Http\Request; You can try adding the Request and set Sentry tag  request()->headers->get('YOUR_CUSTOM_EVENT', 'DTag');
